# pyotrch distributed: Running shell command

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, subprocess, distributed-training

I'm running a [distributed pytorch training](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html). Everything works like charm. I am fully utilizing all GPUs, all processes are in sync, everything is fine.
At the end of each epoch, I want to run some elaborate evaluation in a *new* process (not to block the training):

```py
if args.rank == 0:
  # only for the "main" rank
  subprocess.run(['python3', 'my_eval_code.py', '--chk', 'checkpoint'])
```

At this point, execution stops, the new process is *not* started and everything just halts.

1. Is there some interdependence between pytorch's DDP and `subprocess` module?
2. How can I start a new shell script (`subprocess.run`/`subprocess.call`/`subprocess.Popen`) from inside a `DDP` process?

I also posted this question on [pytorch's forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pyotrch-distributed-running-shell-command/127674?u=shaibagon), and opened a [bug report](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/62381).

---

**Update (July 29th, 2021)**
I changed my code to:

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(f'\t{proc}={proc.poll()}')
try:
  proc_o, proc_e = proc.communicate(timeout=120)
  print(f'successfully communicated o={proc_o} e={proc_e} poll={proc.poll()}')
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
  proc.kill()
  proc_o, proc_e = proc.communicate()
  print(f'time out o={proc_o} e={proc_e} poll={proc.poll()}')
```

No good: the `Popen` command is blocking, the print of the `poll` command is never executed, let alone the `communicate`.
When I check on the job with `top`, I see:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
37924 bagon     39  19   23640   2796    880 S  15.8  0.1   0:15.34 python3
```

Looking at the process that actually runs:
I see this:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
bagon    37924 37065  1 08:00 ?        SNl    0:15 /home/bagon/.conda/envs/my_env/bin/python3 -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=50, pipe_handle=54) --multiprocessing-fork
```

It seems like there is some underlying mechanism preventing `subprocess` module from starting new processes.

Any help?

Comment: Interdependence with `subprocess` not likely... Interdependence between your eval script and training script: more likely. You should try to check the stdout and stderr output from the  subprocess call to see if an error is causing the deadlock. Also `subprocess.run` blocks until the process returns. If you want concurrent execution, you probably want `popen` rather than `run`.

Comment: @Aaron I tried `popen` as well as `call` I did not het any output from the subprocess

Comment: `popen.poll` will tell you if the executable is still running, and you can redirect stdout and stderr to `sys.stdout` in the constructor to make output go to the same shell as the main process. otherwise you have to set the outputs to `subprocess.PIPE` and call `popen.communicate` to get things printed by your script.

Comment: @Aaron i don't think anything is running. I tried `top` but did not see any new process

Comment: if an error is occurring, the process may only exist for a few milliseconds. This is why checking the return code via `poll` and stdout and stderr is important.

Comment: @Aaron thank you for your advices. please see my update - I tried `Popen`, `poll` and `communicate` - to no avail...